# Cursor jumping when opening link in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have found a weird behavior in Chrome. I have replicated it in the JSFiddle below.

There are a few buttons on the left side. When hovering over a button a label is displayed and when clicking it, a link is opened in a new window.

Here is the weird behavior: you hover over the first button, the label is displayed, you click the button, the link is opened in a new tab. But when you switch back to the first tab, without your cursor entering the page itself (just sitting over the tab name), the label of the first button is closed and the label of the 3rd button is opened. Once the cursor enters the page, the label of the 3rd button is closed.

I have done some testing and I have found that when you open the link, the cursor jumps right a few pixels and down a few tens of pixels.

In the JSFiddle example, it jumps 4px right and 70px down. In the files on my computer (not the exact code but a bigger project), it jumps 5px right and 77px down.

I have written some JavaScript for debugging that shows the over, out and click events, the mouse x and y as well as the button for which the event occurs. The data is shown in the browser console.

This problems happens only in Chrome. In other browsers it does not.

What do you think is causing it?

http://jsfiddle.net/7mn0ygh5/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="menu">
    <a class="b1" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="button"></div>
        <div class="label">Label</div>
    </a>
    <a class="b2" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="button"></div>
        <div class="label">Label</div>
    </a>
    <a class="b3" href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">
        <div class="button"></div>
        <div class="label">Label</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    left: 2px;
    top: 10px;
}
.menu > a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
.button {
    background-color: #0088ff;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.label {
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: #00aaff;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    display: none;
}
.menu > a:hover .label {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: @j08691 I am seeing this in the files on my computer, I have replicated it in the JSFiddle and the same and I have also uploaded my files online and the error occurs. I thought it might be something with Chrome. But maybe my Chrome is bugged or something? I guess I will have to test on a different Chrome install.

Comment: I'm seeing the behaviour he describes. Make sure your mouse remains outside the browser window when you close the tab. Using chrome 42.0.2311.152 and 43.0.2357.65

Comment: Do you think, this is a real issue for your application? I think it is better to implement other parts then solve this "little problem".

Comment: Ah, now I see it. Once I clicked the link and the new tab opened, I clicked on the original tab, but that didn't produce the issue. I had to close the newly opened tab to see it, although it doesn't happen consistently to me.

Comment: @j08691 It is happening consistently to me, even without closing the new tab but make sure that your cursor stays out of the page area.

Comment: @Robin I as well was using Chrome 42.0, updated it to 43.0 and the error occurred in both.